# Ignore substring in the end of string using python

Tags: python, string, pandas

I Have data

```
213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:36],"CONNECT api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com:443",200 0,"SafariShared/601.1.46.42 (iPhone4,1; iPhone OS 13C75) Safari/601.1",9443 api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com 443 1856
213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:36],"CONNECT init.itunes.apple.com:443",200 0,"MobileSafari/601.1 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15.0.0",9443 init.itunes.apple.com 443 50073
213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:54],"GET http://www.rbc.ru/ajax/getnewsfeed/?",304 292,"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13C75 Safari/601.1",9443 www.rbc.ru 80 9547
213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:56],"GET http://www.rbc.ru/ajax/mainjson/?",200 99535,"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13C75 Safari/601.1",9443 www.rbc.ru 80 0
213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:58],"CONNECT api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com:443",200 0,"SafariShared/601.1.46.42 (iPhone4,1; iPhone OS 13C75) Safari/601.1",9443 api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com 443 40633
213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:23:58],"GET https://api-glb-ams.smoot.apple.com.js",200 381,"SafariShared/601.1.46.42 (iPhone4,1; iPhone OS 13C75) Safari/601.1",9443 - 443 40633
213.87.137.33 - - [14/Apr/2016:17:24:02],"CONNECT init.itunes.apple.com:443",200 0,"MobileSafari/601.1 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15.0.0",9443 init.itunes.apple.com 443 57391
```

I should ignore some `urls` that contains some word at the end of the `url`.

I try

```
import pandas as pd

colnames = ["used_at", "url", "smth", "browser", "smth2"]
df = pd.read_csv('urls.csv', names=colnames, header=None, sep='""', engine="python")
df['url'] = df['url'].str.strip(',')
urls = df['url']
ignore = ('.jpg', '.js', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png', '.xml', '.json', '.css', '.swf', 'svg', 'ico', '.cur')
for url in urls:
    if not url.startswith('GET'):
        continue
    elif url.endswith(word for word in ignore):
        continue
    else:
        print url
```

But it return `TypeError: endswith first arg must be str, unicode, or tuple, not generator`

Comment: You can use the vectorised `.str.startswith` and `str.contains` to do what you doing.

Comment: endswith accepts a tuple so you can just use `url.endswith(ignore)`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to use `ignore` directly:

```
ignore = ('.jpg', '.js', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png', '.xml', '.json', '.css', '.swf', 'svg', 'ico', '.cur')
for url in urls:
    if not url.startswith('GET'):
        continue
    elif url.endswith(ignore): #use ignore directly here
        continue
    else:
        print url
```

This is because `endswith` can be used with tuple.

Comment: @hellmoore yep. Python is beautiful for such processing. :)

Answer (score 0):

### Change

```
elif url.endswith(word for word in ignore):
```

### to

```
elif any(url.endswith(word) for word in ignore)
```

It reads quite nicely: **if any url ends with word from ignore, then do something.**

Answer (score 0):

You can first create `ignore_li` with `join` by `|` (`or`) and then filter `DataFrame` by [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html), get last `5` chars by `str[]` and use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html). Last return only column `url` by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
ignore = ('.jpg', '.js', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png', '.xml',
          '.json', '.css', '.swf', 'svg', 'ico', '.cur')
ignore_li = '|'.join(ignore)

print df.loc[df.url.str.startswith('GET') & ~(df.url.str[-5:].str.contains(ignore_li)),'url']

0                        GET http://www.livejournal.com/
1      GET http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/activ...
2      GET http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/activ...
3      GET http://rtax.criteo.com/delivery/rta/rta.js...
4      GET http://l-stat.livejournal.net/tmpl/??Widge...
5      GET http://xc3.services.livejournal.com/ljcoun...
7                     GET http://montblanc.rambler.ru/mb
8      GET http://awaps.yandex.ru/0/9999/001001.gif?0...
9      GET http://www.tns-counter.ru/V13a***R%3E*sup_...
10     GET http://b.scorecardresearch.com/b?c1=2&c2=1...
11     GET http://l-api.livejournal.com/__api/?callba...
12     GET http://l-api.livejournal.com/__api/?callba...
13     GET http://www.tns-counter.ru/V13a****rambler_...
15     GET http://www.tns-counter.ru/V13a****rambler_...
16     GET http://www.tns-counter.ru/V13a****rambler_...
```